# ,org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection pool error Timeout waiting for idle object

Tags: java, apache, sql-server-2008, tomcat

I am getting the following error while creating a connection using tomcat server.

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection pool error Timeout waiting for idle object

My JNDI configuration is as under:

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/XXX"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433/ABC" 
    username="XXX"
    password="XXX"
    maxActive="30"
    maxIdle="10"
    maxWait="5000"
    validationQuery="SELECT getDate()"
    poolPreparedStatements="true" />
```

Here is my java code.

package com.ef.clients.ptcl;

```
 import java.sql.CallableStatement;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.SQLException;

 import javax.naming.Context;
 import javax.naming.InitialContext;
 import javax.sql.DataSource;

 import com.audium.server.AudiumException;
 import com.audium.server.session.ActionElementData;
 import com.audium.server.voiceElement.ActionElementBase;

 public class ABC extends ActionElementBase {

DataSource ds; 
public GetCallerCountNew(){
    Context initialContext;
    try{
        initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/XXX");
    }catch(Exception ex){
    }
}

CallableStatement proc = null;
Connection connection = null;
String ani = null; 
String dnis = null;
@Override
public void doAction(String arg0, ActionElementData data) throws AudiumException {


    try {   
            long time_1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            data.addToLog("Entered in getCallerCount class:",null);
            ani = (String) data.getSessionData("ani");
            dnis = (String) data.getSessionData("dnis");

                //going to get connection.
            if (ds == null) {
                data.addToLog("DataSource isn't established.", null);
                throw new AudiumException("DataSource isn't established.");
            }
            connection = ds.getConnection();
            if (connection == null) {
                data.addToLog("Connection isn't established.", null);
                throw new AudiumException("Connection isn't established.");
            }

            // Reading Caller Count
            int WirelineCountToday;
            int WireLessCountToday;
            int TotalCountToday;
            proc = null;
            proc = connection.prepareCall("{ call Custom_Db_Expertqueue_GetCallerCount(?,?,?,?,?) }");

            data.addToLog("Setting ANI: ",ani);
            String parameters = "ANI: " + ani + " DNIS: " + dnis;
            data.addToLog("Calling Stroed proceedure with parameters . ", parameters);

            proc.setString(1, ani); 
            proc.setString(2, dnis); 
            proc.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            proc.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            proc.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

            data.addToLog("Stroed proceedure executed successfully. ", null);



            int out = proc.executeUpdate();

            // getting output parameters from strored proceedure
            WirelineCountToday=proc.getInt(3);//  getInt(1);
            WireLessCountToday=proc.getInt(4);
            TotalCountToday=proc.getInt(5);

            // setting session values 
            data.setSessionData("WirelineCount", WirelineCountToday);
            data.setSessionData("WirelessCount", WireLessCountToday);
            data.setSessionData("TotalCount", TotalCountToday);

            data.addToLog("WirelineCountToday Value Retrieved:", Integer.toString(WirelineCountToday));
            data.addToLog("TotalCountToday Value Retrieved:", Integer.toString(TotalCountToday));
            data.addToLog("WireLessCountToday Value Retrieved:", Integer.toString(WireLessCountToday));

            data.addToLog("Returned value from proceedure is:", Integer.toString(out));
            data.addToLog("for Information.... SUCCESS = 0, FAILURE=1", null);


            long time_2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            data.addToLog("Total Execution Time is: ", time_2-time_1+" ms");
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      { data.addToLog("Exeption while creating connection: ", e.toString()); }

      finally {
          data.addToLog("Going to close connection and callStatement.", null);
          try {
              if(proc !=null){
                  proc.close();
                  data.addToLog("callStatement Closed Successfully.", null);
              }
              else{
                  data.addToLog("callStatement is null..", null);
              }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
            data.addToLog("ERROR WHILE TRYING TO CLOSE STATEMENT. MESSAGE IS: ", e.toString());
          }
          proc = null;
          try {
              if(connection != null) { 
                  connection.close();
                  data.addToLog("Connection closed successfully.", null);
              }
              else{
                  data.addToLog("Connection is null..", null);
              }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
            data.addToLog("ERROR WHILE TRYING TO CLOSE CONNECTINO. MESSAGE IS: ", e.toString());
          }
          connection = null;    
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have solve the issue. I have modified the two things, 1.  maxActive="30" to 100 and  maxIdle="10" to 30. Secondly I created a new stored procedure that resolve the issue.